# Why we can not prove the following by use of integration by parts in probability theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

We know that the expectation of a non-negative random variable is written as follows $$E[x]=\int_0^{\infty}[1-F_X(x)]dx=\int_0^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx$$ I want to ask why we cannot prove through integration by parts that $\int_0^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx$ results in $\int_0^{\infty}[1-F_X(x)]dx$? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the proof you have in mind?

Comment: @saulspatz we know the integration by parts formula as follows $$\int h(x)g'(x)dx=h(x)g(x)-\int h'(x)g(x)dx $$ Now if I put $g'(x)=f_{X}(x)$ and $h(x)=x$ then this by parts formula does not proof the relation provided in my post. On the other hand if we use $g(x)=F_X(x)-1$ and $h(x)=x$ then the integration by parts formula can prove the relation provided in my post. Although with $g(x)=F_X(x)-1$ we can show that the derivative of $g(x)$ is the PDF  but if we integrate the PDF $f_X(x)$ then we do not get $F_{X}(x)-1$ so I think there should be some explanation.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what do you mean by "if we integrate the PDF $f_X(x)$ then we do not get $F_X(x)−1$"? Certainly $F_X(x) - 1$ is an antiderivative of $f_X(x)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee we know that $P(X \leq x)=F_{X}(x)=\int_0^{\infty}^xf_X(x)dx $ This is the formula used. Now I am sure there is some major conceptual mistake that I am making but unfortunately I do not know what it is.

Comment: @SangchulLee I will be grateful if I could see that $\int_{0}^{x}f_{X}(x)dx=F_X(x)-1$

Comment: @FrankMoses, Of course it is not. But the point is that, in the integration by parts formula, you have freedom to choose your favorite antiderivative to plug in. Stated in a more explicit way, the following formula is true for any constant $c$: $$ \int h(x) g'(x) \, dx = h(x)[g(x) + c] - \int h'(x)[g(x) + c] \, dx$$ I guess you will easily figure out why $c$ does not matter here.

Comment: @SangchulLee thank you for your comment. Okay for other general integration by parts we can chose our favorite anti-derivatve and the value of $c$ will not matter. But why it should be $-1$ here?

Comment: The catch is that the above formula is true in a nice circumstance (such as, $h'$ and $g'$ are continuous on an interval $[a, b]$ and the antiderivative is considered as functions on it). But in your question, you are dealing with 'improper integrals', which are limits of integrals. So you have to care for convergence issue as well. And it turns out that the choice $F_X(x) - 1$ is the only choice for which the integral converges (assuming that $X$ has finite expectation).

Comment: @SangchulLee thank you Sang Chul Lee.

Comment: Glad it helped :)